# Covering each point of the plane with circles three times

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, geometry

The following problem arose from an Italian discussion group: I am not so sure about the optimal tags for the question, so feel free to improve them.

*Definition*: we say that $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ admits a *cover* with degree $d$ if there is a family $\mathscr{F}$ of distinct circles (with positive radii) such that every point of $E$ belongs to exactly $d$ circles in $\mathscr{F}$.

*Preliminary results*:

1. There is a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{O\}$ with degree $1$ given by concentric circles;
2. There is no cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with degree $1$, due to the accumulation point of any chain of nested circles;
3. There is a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with degree $2$, for instance the one given by the unit circles centered at $(2n,y)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z},y\in\mathbb{R}$;
4. There is a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{O\}$ with degree $2$, for instance the one given by the circles tangent to the sides of a quadrant.

Now the actual question, which I did not manage to tackle (yet):

**Is there a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with degree $3$?**

---

I believe the answer is negative: I (unsuccessfully) tried to prove that any degree-3 cover admits a degree-2 subcover, in order to get a contradictory degree-1 cover by switching to the complement. Any insight is welcome.

*Small update*: actually it is not possible to extract a degree-2 subcover from a (hypothetical) degree-3 cover. Once a circle $\Gamma_1$ is removed from a degree-3 cover, we are forced to remove a circle contained in the interior of $\Gamma_1$ and this leads to a chain of circles converging to a point.

If a cover with degree 3 exists, every chain of contained circles has a finite number of elements. The elements of $\mathscr{F}$ form a POset: we may say that $\Gamma_1 < \Gamma_2$ if $\Gamma_1$ is contained in the interior of $\Gamma_2$. This also allows to assign a parity to each element of $\mathscr{F}$ and each point of the plane, according to the length of a maximal chain contained in the circle / surrounding such point.

*Further thoughts*: let us assume that a degree-3 cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ exists. By the chain argument there is a disk $D$ such that $\partial D\in\mathscr{F}$ and every circle covering $\mathring{D}$ meets $\partial D$ at two non-antipodal points. Let us name $\mathscr{f}$ the family of circles covering $\mathring{D}$. We have that $\partial D$ is covered three times, so the circles traversing each point of $\partial D$ are $\partial D$ itself and *two* elements of $\mathscr{f}$. These couples of circles "exiting" from any point of $S^1=\partial D$ have to cover *three* times any point of $\mathring{D}$, which is pretty strange. Many sub-questions came to my mind:

1. Is it possible to partition $\mathscr{f}$ into two/three subfamilies of disjoint circles?
2. Is it possible to use the descending chain condition as a substitute for continuity, then apply some topological trick?
3. Are [Tucker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker%27s_lemma), [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) or the theory of planar graphs useful in some way?

Starting from any $P_0\in\partial D$ we may take $P_{-1}$ and $P_1$ as the points of $\partial{D}$ connected to $P_0$ via the elements of $\mathscr{f}$ through $P_0$, then define $P_{-2},P_{2},P_{-3},P_{3},\ldots$ in the same way. This gives a partition of $\partial D$ into finite cycles (a cycle of length $2$ might occur if $P_1=P_{-1}$) and "infinite cycles" with a numerability of elements. Infinite cycles have limit points, which are troublesome. On the other hand also a partition into finite cycles only does not seem to stand any chance of covering any point of $\mathring{D}$ exactly three times.

*Yet another measure-theoretic thought*. Let $S^1=\partial D$ (which we may assume to have radius $1$), let $P\in S^1$. Two elements of $\mathscr{f}$ go through $P$: let $L(P)$ be the total length of the arcs given by the intersections with $\mathring{D}$. Let us assume that $L:S^1\to (0,4\pi)$ is an integrable function. By integrating $L$ over $S^1$ we have that each arc in $\mathscr{f}\cap\mathring{D}$ is counted twice, hence
$$ \int_{S_1} L = 2\int_{\text{arcs in }\mathscr{f}} 1=2\cdot 3\text{Area}(D) = 6\pi$$
and the average length of an arc in $\mathscr{f}$ is $\frac{3}{2}$. It follows that most of the arcs of an "integrable 3-cover" of $\mathring{D}$ are pretty short, forcing a concentration of the arcs near the boundary of $D$. This violation of uniformity probably leads to the fact that if a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with degree $3$ exists, it is not integrable.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but isn't the union of covers 1 and 3 a degree 3 cover of $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{O\}$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: yes it is, by suitably overlapping 1. and 3. you get a degree-3 cover of the punctured plane. You also have covers of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with any even degree, by overlapping instances of 2. with different radii.

Comment: Perhaps investigate whether a 3-cover of the plane by circles implies a 3-cover by straight lines. Just spitballing.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: a 3-cover by lines is trivial: it is enough to consider all the horizontal, vertical or diagonal (meaning parallel to $y=x$) lines.

Comment: Can you get a degree-n covering of the punctured plane by covering $\Bbb R^2$ with $n$ families of lines and then doing a bilinear transformation of the complex plane that exchanges 0 and $\infty$?

Comment: @MJD: yes, through circle inversion you can get a cover of the punctured plane with any degree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below I construct a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with degree $3$. The idea is to build an almost-"degree 2 cover" of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which a single point is covered three times (using variations on the trick from the degree 2 cover given in the question), then to balance things out by adding the degree $1$ cover of $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{O\}$.

**Lemma**:
Let $U$ be an open disk and let $P$ be a point on its boundary. Then there is a family $\mathscr{F}$ of circles contained in $U \cup \{P\}$ such that each point of $U$ belongs to exactly two circles of $\mathscr{F}$, while $P$ belongs to exactly one circle of $\mathscr{F}$.

*Proof*:
For $a > 0$, let $L(a)$ be the line given by the equation $x = a$, and let $C(a)$ be the circle of radius $a$ centered at $(a, 0)$, so $C(a)$ passes through the origin $O$. Assume without loss of generality that $P = O$ and that $U$ is the open disk bounded by $C(1/2)$. Now, for $0 < a < b$, let $\mathscr{G}(a, b)$ be the family of circles of radius $\frac{b-a}{2}$ with centers on the line $L(\frac{b+a}{2})$, so the circles of $\mathscr{G}(a, b)$ are contained within the closed strip bounded by $L(a)$ and $L(b)$, and each point of $L(a)$ and $L(b)$ belongs to exactly one circle of $\mathscr{G}(a, b)$, while each point in the interior of the strip belongs to exactly two circles of $\mathscr{G}(a, b)$. Define
$$\mathscr{G} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathscr{G}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}, 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathscr{G}\left(2 + \frac{1}{n+1}, 2 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \cup \bigcup_{n=3}^\infty \mathscr{G}(n, n+1)$$
so that, if we define $V = \bigcup_{a > 1} L(a) = \{(x, y) : x > 1\}$, all circles in $\mathscr{G}$ are contained in $V$, and each point in $V$ belongs to exactly two circles in $\mathscr{G}$, except for those points in $L(2)$, each of which belongs to exactly one circle in $\mathscr{G}$. Now, under [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) with respect to the unit circle centered at the origin, $L(a)$ maps to $C(\frac{1}{2a}) - \{O\}$, $V$ maps to $U$, and each circle in $\mathscr{G}$ maps to a circle in a new family $\mathscr{G}'$ of circles contained in $U$. By the above, each point in $U$ belongs to exactly two circles in $\mathscr{G}'$, except for those points on $C(1/4) - \{O\}$, each of which belongs to exactly one circle in $\mathscr{G}'$. To conclude, we define $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{G}' \cup \{C(1/4)\}$, which has the desired properties.

**Proposition**:
There is a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with degree $3$.

*Proof*:
Define $C'(r)$ to be the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Let $P = (2, 0)$ and let $U$ be the open disk bounded by $C'(2)$. For each $n \geq 1$, let $\mathscr{H}_n$ be the family of unit circles with centers on $C'(2n+1)$, so if we let $E_n$ be the interior of the region bounded by $C'(2n)$ and $C'(2n+2)$, then each circle in $\mathscr{H}_n$ is contained in $C'(2n) \cup E_n \cup C'(2n+2)$, and each point in $E_n$ belongs to exactly two circles in $\mathscr{H}_n$, while each point on $C'(2n)$ or $C'(2n+2)$ belongs to exactly one circle in $\mathscr{H}_n$. Letting $\mathscr{H} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathscr{H}_n$, we see that each point in $\mathbb{R}^2 - (C'(2) \cup U)$ belongs to exactly two circles in $\mathscr{H}$, each point in $C'(2)$ belongs to exactly one circle in $\mathscr{H}$, and each point in $U$ belongs to zero circles in $\mathscr{H}$. To cover $U$, let $\mathscr{F}$ be the family of circles given by the Lemma applied to $U$ and $P$, and define $\mathscr{F}' = \mathscr{F} \cup \mathscr{H} \cup \{C'(2)\}$, so each point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ belongs to exactly two circles in $\mathscr{F}'$, except $P$ which belongs to exactly three (since it lies on $C'(2)$). But none of the circles in $\mathscr{F}'$ are centered at $P$, so we can extend the family $\mathscr{F}'$ to a covering of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with degree $3$ by adding all circles centered at $P$.

Comment: Great answer! As far as I can tell, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

It can be proved that $k$-fold covering exists for any $k\geqslant 3$ -- if you are allowed to use transfinite induction (ie, basically, Zermelo's axiom of choice).

If we are given some set of circumferences, we will call the number of circumferences passing through some point $a$ a *coverage* number of that point.

Now, well-order the points of the plane $P$ so that for every $x\in P$ set $a \prec x$ has cardinality strictly less than continuum. Then we define statement $S(x)$ as follows:

*There exists a less than continuum-large set $C_x$ of distinct circumferences so that*

*(a) every point on the plane preceding $x$ is covered by exactly $k$ circumferences from $C_x$;*

*(b) every other point is covered by no more than $k$ circumferences from $C_x$;*

*(c) for every $y\prec x$ we have $C_y \subset C_x$.*

The base: for minimal $z\in P$ statement $S(z)$ is obvious as $C_z$ can be chosen as some $k$ distinct circumferences passing through $z$.

Now for the induction step. Let $x\in P$ be an arbitrary point and assume that for every $y \prec x$ statement $S(y)$ is true. Consider now the union $U$ of all $C_y$, $y\prec x$. Obviously, every point on the plane is covered by $U$ no more than $k$ times, and every point $y\prec x$ is covered exactly $k$ times.

It remains to add to $U$ a few circumferences to ensure that $x$ is covered exactly $k$ times, without breaking property (b).

Let us assume that $x$ is covered by $k-p$ circumferences in $U$, where $p>0$.

Consider now all the circumferences passing through $x$ - there is a continuum of them. Since cardinality of $U$ is less than continuum, and since any two distinct circumferences intersect in at most two points, it follows that the set $A$ of points which are covered $2$, $3$, ..., or $k$ times by $U$ has cardinality of less than continuum. Therefore, we can find $p$ circumferences which pass through $x$ but not through any of the points of $A$. Adding these $p$ circumferences to $U$ will increase the coverage number of every point on the plane, other than $x$, by at most $2$. Since these circumferences do not pass through any point of $A$, they only pass through points covered once or less, thus increasing their coverage number to at most $3\leqslant k$. This proves $S(x)$ and concludes the induction step.

---

This is, of course, a pure existence proof, without any direct construction of such a covering.

Answer (score 0):

Also, obviously, there is an explicit construction of a $k$-fold covering where $k$ is even. Just take any $2$-fold covering - like the one from item (c) in the
original post - and repeat it $k/2$ times.

Similarly, if you have a $3$-fold covering you can create $k$-fold covering for any odd $k > 3$ by adding extra $2$-fold coverings on top of it.